# Outlook Calendar syncs from Win10 Phone to Win10 desktop but not the other way around

Tags: sync, windows-10, outlook, windows-10-mobile

Whenever I create/modify an event on my Windows 10 Phone, it automatically gets synced on my Windows 10 PC but the same does not apply the other way around. I've also checked my Outlook calendar on outlook.com and not surprisingly none of the changes I make on the PC gets synced there. Is there anyway for the sync process to work both ways?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the sync from the desktop being really, really slow - how often is that set to sync?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I have tried this on different PCs. Also how do you set sync interval? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default sync speed is "based on my usage", which can leave it a long while before it syncs back. I'd suggest changing the pc to synchronise "as items arrive" (assuming on power, with non metered internet connection); the phone we'll them notice the change a lot quicker...